# Windows Server 2012 R2 - User Account Single App

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2012

I have a Windows Server 2012 R2 with multiple user accounts. One account ("test") is configured in such a way that on logon a program is started and when the program is closed the account is automatically logged out. This "test" account can log in via Remote Desktop or directly (the server is a Hyper-V machine). Other accounts behave normally.

I need to create a "test2" account with same properties and can't figure out how. As far as I can tell this is neither Kiosk-Mode, nor "Single App Terminal Server" and I'm completely lost. The server is also not part of any domain and it doesn't have Active Directory.

What could it be, where should I look?

**UPDATE**

It turns out, the app is set up as user shell (`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Shell`), which I actually knew was a possibility - but searching the registry for the app name resulted in nothing, because `HKEY_USERS` doesn't have keys for every single user, only for the "actively loaded user profiles".

Comment: most probably the program is just set as the users shell.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Thank you, you are right. I couldn't find the setting in registry because I wasn't aware `HKEY_USERS` doesn't load ALL users, only active ones... >:|